# Can I set new tab to show home page?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

The choice of what to show in new tab is rather poor (TB 9.0.9):

[image: Screenshot of new tab options (blank or about)]

I'd like to get home page in it.. is this possible via some more configuration and is this limitation deliberate? (I'm seeing some questions with answers suggesting something is restricted by design for security, but I don't see how this secures me if home page is shown by default already, when TB starts)

Ideally, there should be an option to show an arbitrary page configured separately from home page, but it's ok to use home page too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tor Browser is based on Firefox, and Firefox does not have this feature either. So it's not that the Tor Browser removed the option, it's that Firefox doesn't have this feature.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1118285
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1452144

While installing extensions in the Tor Browser is not recommended, that might be the only way to get this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Type `about:config` in URL and Search/Filter for `browser.startup.homepage` and change the value `about:tor` to the page you want as a home page. Works for me on Tor Browser Bundle v9.0.9. You'll need to restart the browser afterwards.

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it looks like you are suggesting a way to change home page, not new tab, aren't you?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought you were talking about setting the home page.